# Object A make Object B expand on ingoing and then shrink on outgoing

Tags: animation, modifiers, objects, collision

I like to create a animation where a "bullet-like-objekt" hits an object ("cube") and then the object shall expand from the bullet. And when the bullet goes through the object shall enter the normal state again.

Here is some prints of how i like to have it:

Normalstate:
[image: When the bullet is outside of the cube]

Inside 1:
[image: When the bullet have entered the cube]

Inside 2:
[image: When the bullet is about to exiting the cube]

On the other side:
[image: When the bullet is on the other side of the cube]

I just trying to understand how the object can interact with eachother so I then can make an animation.

Thanks!

Comment: You can use Cast modifier for Cube and set bullet as Object in modifier to controll effect. https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/modeling/modifiers/deform/cast.html#options

Comment: Thanks, that helped it!
I just need to learn the modifier and then I thinks it will be awesome!

Comment: Cast modifier as Vklidu says, Lattice modifier would work as well

Comment: or you use shape keys ;)

Comment: @moonboots and then scale the lattice after the bullet?
I dont understand the Lattice function in this :)

Chris: Ah yes the shape keys! Well I tryed but I found it very hard to get a good solution.

Comment: you can parent the lattice to the bullet, and give a Lattice modifier to the object you want to deform, then when you'll move the bullet, the lattice will deform the object when crossing it

Comment: I still dont get it, its the parenting thing :)
I have a Lattice modifier with "Lattice" on my cube. Should I make "Lattice" parent or child to the "bullet"?

Comment: @Chris, shapekeys will be a bit complicated for complicated object imho

Comment: @moonboots you are totally right. But the objects which are shown here look simple 

Comment: @Chris  it still seems a bit p*in in the *ss to use shapekeys even for such a simple shape but I may be wrong. The deformation acts like a kind of wave through the object, not so easy

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As Vklidu says you can use the *Cast* modifier, you can also use the *Lattice* modifier:

Create a lattice, scale it in *Object* mode so that it can contain the cube object that it is supposed to deform, put it at the same position as the bullet, parent it to the bullet, give your lattice a bit of *Resolution* in the *Object Data* panel, modify it in *Edit* mode so that it has the deforming shape you want, give your cube object a *Lattice* modifier with the lattice as lattice *Object*:

[image]

Now when you move your bullet the lattice follows and deforms the cube:

[image]

Comment: It seams kinda tricky to use Lattice, the cube follows the bullet if i move it along the Z-angle. But I believe it to be my experience with Lattice and Blender thats need to be better! Anyhow thanks, it solved my problem!

Comment: yes you're right if the bullet moves on the Z axis it won't work fine, so Cast modifier is probably the best solution if you need a more complicated movement, it will wok fine for a simple deformation

Comment: you can play with the modifier's Strength value though, it may help if you want to deactivate it